# Create excel without interop and template with or without row and columnspan

Tags: c#, xls

Which dll or library can be used to create the excelsheet which is not of a particular format such that a template can be used in this context. While the rows and columns may be merged. Number of columns are not fixed.

For example: In the first row column 1 and 2 are merged while in the second row the 2 rows of second column are merged. Say first row is containing 5 columns while the second row is of 4 columns.

Interop is not desired as the system running the program may not have Microsoft office installed with it.

Any suggestions would be a great helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options out there (free and commercial):

- [OpenXML 2.0 from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free)
- [NPOI](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/) (free)
- [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) (commercial)
- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)
- [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) (commercial)

Another option (though not really recommended) is to generate a HTML file with specific tags - supported by Excel as per MS documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx . For a sample of this including source code see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Yahia for the links. I would surely notify you as soon I could find which one suits well to my working.

Comment: you are welcome - please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answers that are of help...

Comment: I know it really late to reply, but it helped me a lot. I did used NPOI for the same :) Thanks