# Writing and Executing VBA Macros on Excel without using Excel.Interop

Tags: c#, excel

**Scope:**

I am generating automated reports using excel, but since we have restrictions on our server, we can't install `Excel.Interop` or use any `COM` object to perform such action.

We have been using [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) as our main helper on this task but it has some serious restrictions when it comes to more intricated things such as `PivotCharts` and `Macros`.

We have just finished the project, missing only the `PivotCharts` since EPPLUS has no support for them.

**Question:**

How can we :

**A)** Write Macros to a `.xlsm` file? (We could write one named "Auto_Open" so that excel would run it uppon opening, creating the charts and stuff)

**OR**

**B)** Run a macro within our code to generate those charts after putting all the needed data there?

Not using `Excel.Interop` is a must at this moment. We are open for some suggestions such as 
[SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) and [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com/), but we can't find any sample or piece of code that actually shows how to Write or Run macros.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17):

I realise this question is a bit old, but in the interest of helping future visitors I'll add that the current version of EPPlus (4.0.4 at time of writing) supports the inclusion of VBA.

Where `excelDoc` is your `ExcelPackage`, you can drop it in using something along the lines of:

```
excelDoc.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();

StringBuilder vbaCode = new StringBuilder();

vbaCode.AppendLine("Private Sub Workbook_Open()");
vbaCode.AppendLine("    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False");
vbaCode.AppendLine("End Sub");

excelDoc.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = vbaCode.ToString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you actually execute the vba code once you have put it in the workbook?

Comment: @VanceSmith In the above example, because the code is within the Workbook_Open subroutine, it will execute automatically upon opening the workbook.

Comment: that is until the macros are blocked due to an over zealous security area which defaults all settings and blocks macros....so, no workbook_open events will fire

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Excel
2. Press Alt+F11

You will now be in the VBA IDE.

To run something on Auto Open:

1. Select `ThisWorkbook` From the VBAProject in Project Explorer on the Left of your screen
2. There are Two drop downs  near the top of the window one will say `(General)` and The other `(Declarations)` click on `(General)` and select  workbook

Excel should automatically bring you to the `Open` declaration.

Anything written in this sub will execute on open.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need the report generator to be fully automated, with no human output.

Also, EPPLUS has no support for opening xlsm (macro enabled) files, so there's no way i can do this by hand.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins Then you might have to look inot using the (Open XML SDK)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx]

Comment: The OP asks how to add macros without Excel Interop so I assume they don't have the luxury of manually adding a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to programatically write macros to an xlsm file, why don't you create a template that already contains the macros you want.  Then generate your reports from this template.

When a user opens the report (and allows macros to run), then your macro will run and do the manipultations you want (your option A).  Your Auto_Open macro could check some suitable condition (e.g. presence of a value in a specific location, perhaps on a VeryHidden sheet so the user can't easily interfere with it) before doing any work, so that it doesn't run when you open an "empty" template.

As for your option B (run the macro before providing the report to the user): this isn't feasible without Excel Automation.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to mention that EPPLUS does not open xlsm files, so there's no way we can setup a template and work from there. That was our first approach, but it does not worked.