# How to add a VBA function to an Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

My C# program creates an Excel file, I want this file to have a VBA function (so the user could change something without rerunning the program).
How can I do this?

Comment: Could something like this be helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303872 ?

Comment: @mmvsbg - This was exactly what I needed, thank you.
further questions:
1. When trying to save using the .xlsm extansion i'm required by Excel to "choose a macro enabled file type", what could be the reason for that? When saving manually this does nor occur.
2. I want my function to be part of the Worksheet_Change() sub, how can I do that?

Comment: @proton, if you have new questions, you may want to create a new StackOverflow question.  Be sure to include details such as any issues you have and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do it using the [OpenXML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124).

And parts of [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331711/c-how-to-inject-vba-code-into-excel-xlsm-without-using-vba-project-object-mod/8368076).