# Sorting on cell color in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

My code crashes with the error message - "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."

I'm trying to sort on cell color. This is my code:

```
_wks.Sort.SortFields.Clear();
_wks.Sort.SortFields.Add(
    DupesColumn, 
    XlSortOn.xlSortOnCellColor,
    XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
_wks.Sort.SortFields[1].SortOnValue.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRoyalBlue;

_wks.Sort.SetRange(DupesColumn.CurrentRegion);
_wks.Sort.Header = XlYesNoGuess.xlYes;
_wks.Sort.MatchCase = false;
_wks.Sort.Orientation = XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows;
_wks.Sort.SortMethod = XlSortMethod.xlPinYin;
_wks.Sort.Apply();
```

DupesColumn is a range. I'm using VS 2013. I tried defining the range as dynamic, didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which line is it breaking on?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is breaking on line:

```
_wks.Sort.SortFields[1].SortOnValue.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRoyalBlue;
```

This will be because the reference to SortFields[1] is not valid as it's zero based. Therefore if you've cleared the SortFields and then added only one to it then it's reference will be 0 not 1. So the following should work:

```
_wks.Sort.SortFields[0].SortOnValue.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRoyalBlue;
```

Comment: It throws the error A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

In fact this is the same error as before, but without the message from Excel 'The sort reference is not valid...'

Comment: So do you know which line it's breaking on?

Comment: It breaks on _wks.Sort.SortFields[0].SortOnValue.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRoyalBlue;

Comment: @Si8 - no, but take a look here to help debug and find the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281425/how-to-avoid-a-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception

Answer (score 0):

It's because of **Orientation** property's value that you set.

This line

```
_wks.Sort.Orientation = XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows;
```

should be

```
_wks.Sort.Orientation = XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns;
```

Further reading:
1) [F# Excel Range.Sort Fails or Rearranges Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39144866/916379)