# How to work with word document using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I want to do the next, but don't know how to do it, please help me.

First, I open the Word document by

```
wordApp.Documents.Open;
```

then I try to save it by another name to make a copy using

```
aDoc.SaveAs(ref saveas...);
```

Now I want to go through the savedAs document word by word. I need to get every word and go through the word letter by letter.

So, actually I want to get the word, check it for some rules, then get read that word letter by letter and make changes (transliterate) to those letters, so in the end I will have the transliterated document. I was trying to write this code using for loop insdie for loop, but I don't know how can I loop the whole document word by word... and at the same time rewrite the new form of word instead of the currently taken word.

Please, help me with right Interop.Word commands to implement this.

Comment: What have you tried? I only see Document.Open; (which is an incorrect statement) and the function SaveAs

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120184/how-to-create-excel-in-my-c-sharp-application-if-msoffice-is-not-installed/13120402#13120402) can help you.

Comment: Google found this for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924056/is-there-a-way-to-read-a-word-document-line-by-line

Comment: top result on google... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5b82c0b5-ecaf-40f2-a68a-c7c17c85414f

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to retrieve words from a word doc

http://zirmandli.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/read-word-doc-using-c/

Document is retrieved by calling this :

```
Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                      ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                      ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                      ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
```